# C# How to pass array of var length to eventhandler

Tags: c#, arrays, variables, eventhandler

I'm trying to read values from serial port in c#.
This is the code for the event handler when new data is received:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    int bytes = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
    counter = bytes;
    byte[] comBuffer = new byte[bytes];
    serialPort1.Read(comBuffer, 0, bytes);
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));

}
```

And this is where the Byte should be written to a textbox but now filled with testcode:

```
private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     counter2 += counter;
     RxString = counter2.ToString();
     textBox1.AppendText(RxString + "\r\n");

}
```

So I'm into C programming but not into C# and would be very thankful if someone could tell me how I can get the `byte[]` array into the eventhandler to do something with the data. My biggest problem is that the length of the array is variable.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why are you calling `DisplayText` as an event? Why not just as a method? I don't understand the pattern you're using here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the standard EventHandler signature, use a method signature more appropriate to your needs:

```
private void DisplayText(string stringToDisplay)
{
     textBox1.AppendText(stringToDisplay + "\r\n");
}
```

In your event handler, convert the byte array into a string and pass it to your DisplayText method:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    int bytes = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
    counter = bytes;
    byte[] comBuffer = new byte[bytes];
    serialPort1.Read(comBuffer, 0, bytes);

    // convert byte array to string
    string stringToShow = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
    this.Invoke(() => DisplayText(stringToShow));
}
```

Note: If your data contains 8-bit characters (exceeding the ASCII range), use the appropriate encoding for converting it to string.

Comment: Basically this, although I still don't know why you'd even use `Invoke`.

Comment: @Yuck: DataReceived probably occurs in a background thread, so Invoke will ensure that the textbox is updated in the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to solve your problem is to create a class derived from EventArgs and an event handler that uses it. Then you can raise this event when data is received.

Event handler :

```
public class MyDataReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
}
```

Event :

```
public event EventHandler<MyDataReceivedEventArgs> DataReceived;
private void OnDataReceived(MyDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if(DataReceived != null) DataReceived(this, e);
}
```

Fire the event when data is received like this :

```
OnDataReceived(new MyDataReceivedEventArgs { Bytes = comBuffer });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something other then `EventHandler`.  `EventHandler` only takes `sender` and `EventArgs` so you need a different delegate type.  I'd use sometihng like:

```
private void DisplayText(object sender, DataEventArgs e)
{
     //e.Data is now available

     counter2 += counter;
     RxString = counter2.ToString();
     textBox1.AppendText(RxString + "\r\n");
}

public class DataEventArgs : EventAgrs
{
    public byte[] Data {get; set;}
}
```

Then call it using

```
byte[] comBuffer = new byte[bytes];
serialPort1.Read(comBuffer, 0, bytes);
this.Invoke(new EventHandler<DataEventArgs>(DisplayText)
          , new DataEventArgs {Data = comBuffer});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need! But when trying to implement this in my code there is shown methodname expected at DisplayText,new DataEventArgs {Data = comBuffer}

Comment: @user3470049 Typo - fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to be annoying but problem is the same :(

Comment: @user3470049 fixed the parentheses.

Comment: Is there any special trick about e.Data? Just tried to access it like an byte array but test stuff like 'counter = e.Data.Length;' doesn't work because of 'System.eventArgs' doesnt contain a definition for 'data' :(

Comment: Did you change the second parameter in the signature from `EventArgs` to `DataEventArgs`?

Comment: Think this was it. Sorry for my incompetence and thank you a lot